# Add value to existing value in hourly intervals with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to write a function that, depending on the time, a value is generated by jQuery, and for every hour it is updated with the new value until it reaches a maximum (a variable set).

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    function randomGenerator(bottom, top) {
        return Math.floor( Math.random() * ( 1 + top - bottom ) ) + bottom;
    }

    var startTime = $('.start-time').val();
    var callLimit = randomGenerator( 120, 180 );
    var callInterval = callLimit/12;

    $('#call-stats').text(
        // at 7am value will equal '0'
        // at 9am value will equal 'callLimit * 2' as 2 hours have passed
        // at 3pm value will equal 'callLimit * 8' as 8 hours have passed
    );

    // Value cannot go above that set in 'callLimit' and the function will reset everyday

});
```

The best way I can think of doing this is by having an `if` statement on the value output by startTime...

```
if( startTime === '07:00' ) {
    $('#call-stats').text('0');
} 
else if( startTime === '08:00' ) {
    $('#call-stats').text(callInterval);
} 
else if( startTime === '09:00' ) {
    $('#call-stats').text(callInterval * 2);
} 
else if( startTime === '10:00' ) {
    $('#call-stats').text(callInterval * 3);
} 
...
```

Has anybody a more efficient way of doing this?

http://jsfiddle.net/Zz2RY/1/

Comment: this looks like a school question?

Comment: No it's not a homework question @infensus

Comment: Definitely not @MilchePatern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
var currentDate = new Date(); 

//Clock is 24 hour
var hour = currentDate.getHours();

//subtract off your start time
 $('#call-stats').text((hour - startTime) * callInterval);
```